# Issue trying to drop a table / migration in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried to implement a gem that uses the same model (comment.rb) as one of the gem I was trying to install before. I have tried rake db:rollback and rake db:rollback VERSION= to come back to the point where I'm supposed not to have any migrations or any tables named 'comment', but sqlite3 keeps telling me that there is a table with that name and it can not move forward.

rake db:migrate:status

```
     Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
    --------------------------------------------------
       up     20140616150625  Devise create users
       up     20140616151746  Create hacks
       up     20140616155718  Acts as taggable on migration.acts as taggable on engine
       up     20140616155719  Add missing unique indices.acts as taggable on engine
       up     20140616155720  Add taggings counter cache to tags.acts as taggable on engine
       up     20140617185601  Add picture to hacks
       up     20140617190705  Add attachment image to hacks
       up     20140617194434  Add name to users
       up     20140617194509  Create identities
       up     20140618125514  Add confirmable to devise
       up     20140619150148  Create comments
       up     20140619162204  The comments change user.the comments engine
      down    20140619162205  The comments create comments.the comments engine
      down    20140619162206  The comments change commentable.the comments engine
      down    20140619163035  Drop comments
```

And the issue - I'm not sure if this called rack trace?

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "comments" already exists: CREATE TABLE "comments" ("id"   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "user_id" integer, "holder_id" integer,  "commentable_id" integer, "commentable_type" varchar(255), "commentable_url" varchar(255), "commentable_title" varchar(255), "commentable_state" varchar(255), "anchor" varchar(255), "title" varchar(255), "contacts" varchar(255), "raw_content" text, "content" text, "view_token" varchar(255), "state" varchar(255) DEFAULT 'draft', "ip" varchar(255) DEFAULT 'undefined', "referer" varchar(255) DEFAULT 'undefined', "user_agent" varchar(255) DEFAULT 'undefined', "tolerance_time" integer, "spam" boolean DEFAULT 'f', "parent_id" integer, "lft" integer, "rgt" integer, "depth" integer DEFAULT 0, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) /Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

I have tried to drop the same table by accessing sqlite3, but I'm not able to access the tables. Any advice?

Comment: if you don't care about data in DB try `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Comment: @gotva same issue StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled - I have uploaded the complete trace here https://gist.github.com/malditojavi/6104f07e31cb367ac46b

Comment: a dirty way: open your IRB console and run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.drop_table :comments` (but it will drop the table and all of its content). Another possibility: create a migration file droping the table right before the other migration that creates it. Still dirty, but works with `rake db:mirate`

Comment: oh, as I understand you have a migration which creates table `comments` (version 20140619150148) and another migration (I think from engine/gem) (version 20140619162205). So it is correct that you have an error. If you would like to use table from gem - remove all custom migrations for comments

Comment: @MrYoshiji Returns a NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord, your first choice. The second option, I tried initally.

Comment: @gotva remove custom migrations is not db:rollback?

Comment: my repo can be found here https://github.com/malditojavi/definitive/commits/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two migrations with table `comments` creating ([one](https://github.com/malditojavi/definitive/blob/80784666ee1e9e2c206190026b758f46b61f7130/db/migrate/20140619150148_create_comments.rb), [second](https://github.com/malditojavi/definitive/blob/80784666ee1e9e2c206190026b758f46b61f7130/db/migrate/20140619162205_the_comments_create_comments.the_comments_engine.rb)). The DB can't create second table with the same name.

About migrations. Main details can be found in the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

`rollback` does not delete migration - it is just revert it (run method down). If you would like to use second table `comments` you have at least two ways:

1. rollback creating the first table. Delete migration (delete physically file). run `rake db:migrate`
2. You can create a new migration which `drop_table comments` then generate a new migration with new version of table `comments` (it is important that timestamp for migration with dropping table was less than timestamp for migration with creating table). After this run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Second choice is not what I got in https://github.com/malditojavi/definitive/blob/80784666ee1e9e2c206190026b758f46b61f7130/db/migrate/20140619163035_drop_comments.rb +         def change
   drop_table :comments
  end on it?

Comment: 1. it is correct in general (except `drop_table` is not reversible migration - it means that you should use `up/down` methods). 2. The problem is in migration timestamps: Rails runs them in direct order. that is why ` 20140619163035_drop_comments` is run too late.

Comment: First option, worked smoothly. Thanks a lot for you help & detailed steps.

Comment: FYI the first option is good for your situation but it is not acceptable for production apps. You can't drop DB on production server - so be careful in the future

Comment: From the 2 options, can we say that 2nd one is more 'best practices'?

Comment: yes it is. Migrations should not be deleted from app. When you generate a migration you should check if it runs `up` and `down` and do not push it unless it works correctly (in your case it looks like you pushed incorrect migration)